# Update the fields of a single row in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have created a table with django model.

```
class Likes(models.Model):
  likes = models.IntegerField(max_length=255,unique=False)
  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.likes
```

Initially I have no records in the row.But I want to count the likes on the page.So I am having a single row which will contain the likes of the page.How should I increment the value likes as soon as user clicks the like button in my view.

Like(view.py):

```
def like(request):
   var=0
   count=Likes.objects.count()
   if(count==0):
      l=Likes(likes=1)
      l.save()
   else:
      l1=Likes()
      l1.likes=int(l1.likes)+1
      l1.save()
      var=l1.likes
return HttpResponse("Likes"+str(var))
```

But this is not working.I just want to increment the likes as soon as user clicks on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from django.db.models import F

likes = models.IntegerField(default=0, max_length=255,unique=False)
```

Then

```
Likes.objects.get_or_create() #remove this after first time (no need of checking every time).
Likes.objects.filter().update(likes = F('likes')+1)
```